# JacksonSerializer doesn't work in Kotlin Lambda

Tags: kotlin, jackson, aws-lambda

When I create a client with the `JacksonSerializer()` feature and make some API calls, then run that script on my local machine, I get no error and the script runs successfully. However, when I upload this script as an AWS Lambda, I get the following error:

```sh
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of kotlin.coroutines.Continuation, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
```

At first, I thought the error originated from me constructing the client outside of the `Handler` class, but when I made the client a private value inside the `Handler` class, I still get the error. I've included `println()` statements in my function, but they don't even run. That tells me that my `handleRequest()` funciton isn't getting run. Is there some AWS/Lambda'ism that prevents me from using the `JacksonSerializer()` feature as? If so, are there any alternatives on how to parse JSON responses with the Ktor client?

My client construction:

```
private val client = HttpClient(Apache) {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = JacksonSerializer()
    }
}
```

An example call using the client:

```
val response = client.post<JsonNode> {
    url(URL(GITHUB_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT))
    body = reqBody
    headers {
        append("Authorization", "bearer $token")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you made your handler function be a kotlin `suspend` function? If so, that's your problem.

When you mark a function `suspend`, the compiler applies a bunch of magic. Most of the time, you don't need to know anything about this, other than the fact that any `suspend` function gets an extra parameter of type `kotlin.coroutines.Continuation` added to its signature. You usually don't notice this, since the compiler also makes calls to the function pass along their own hidden `Continuation` parameter.

`Continuation`, by design, can't be created by a tool like Jackson - it's an internal thing. What you probably need to do (assuming that you did make your handler function `suspend`) is to wrap your method in `runBlocking {}` and make it not be a `suspend` function. It's probably easiest to create a new handler, like so:

```
fun fixedHandler(input: MyInput, context: Context) = runBlocking {
  originalHandler(input, context)
}


suspend fun originalHandler(input: MyInput, context: Context): MyOutput {
  TODO("This is your original code")
}
```

PS - I've usually found it best to leverage the pre-defined Lambda interfaces to write my Lambda functions - it prevents you from encountering issues like this. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html for how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out your dependencies running locally versus your dependencies in AWS? I've had issues where locally I'm running with a version, but the version in AWS was different. That could especially explain the error about continuations... Perhaps the method signature is different in whatever version you're using?

Look especially for `provided` scopes in your gradle/maven pom. Those are easy places for version to be out of sync.